# React-router deeply nested switch route change re-renders all the way to the root app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4

I'm using react-router-dom 4+ version  and redux in my app.

My route structure is as follows:

`index.js`:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <App />
</BrowserRouter>
```

`App.js`:

```
<div className="app">
  <Switch>
    <Redirect exact from="/" to={redirect} />
    <Route path="/auth" component={Auth} />
    <Route path="/dashboard" component={RequireAuth(Main)} />
    <Route component={NotFound} />
  </Switch>
</div>
```

`RequireAuth` is HOC that just checks if user is authorized and returns "Main".

`Main.js`:

```
<div className="main-page">
  <Header url={url} />
  <div className="main-container" style={!!this.props.menuOpen ? { marginLeft: '240px' } : { marginLeft: '0px' }}>
    <Switch>
      <Redirect exact path={url} to={`${url}/tasks`} />
      <Route path={`${url}/tasks`} render={() => <h1>TASKS</h1>} />
      <Route path={`${url}/done`} render={() => <h1>DONE</h1>} />
      <Route path={`${url}/notes`} render={() => <h1>NOTES</h1>} />
      <Route path={`${url}/archive`} render={() => <h1>ARCHIVE</h1>} />
      <Route component={AltNotFound} />
    </Switch>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also `Auth.js` has similar structure as `Main.js`, it has a header of sorts and a switch with 2 routes.

Now my question / problem:

Whenever I navigate nested routes like from dashboard/tasks to dashboard/notes etc. (same in Auth.js) all the app re-renders all the way to `App.js`. I sprinkled console logs in `Main.js` and `App.js` `componentWillMount`, `componentDidMount` and render methods and they all fire every time. Surely that is not what is supposed to happen, right?

What am I doing wrong and what additional information can I provide here to help people answer? I'm sorry this is my very first question.